# How to do routing with Electron and Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, electron, single-page-application

I have been looking for ways to find a way to make a single page application with vanilla javascript only but sadly I could not find one.

I found this code in a tutorial on how to make a SPAs, however the issue is `location.pathname` returns not the URL path but the file path instead with Electron. This bit of code is integral to make the routing work. And I don't wanna use any frameworks.

```
const router = async () => {
  const routes = [
    { path: "/", view: console.log("Viewing /") },
    { path: "/login", view: console.log("Viewing login") },
    { path: "/dashboard", view: console.log("Viewing dashboard") },
  ];

const potentialMatches = routes.map((route) => {
    return {
      route: route,
      isMatch: location.pathname === route.path,
    };
  });
 };

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  router();
});
```

Is there a way I could retrieve the URL path and inject it to my index.js?

Comment: Why don't you want to use frameworks? They do a lot of the work for you and they build into code that is widely compatible.

Comment: If you make your routing based on URL `hash` instead, it will be ok